# How to display data of firestore DocumentReference in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got two collection in my firestore database and It's structure like,

```
Collection1 - movies
   -movieTitle : String
   -movieYear : String
   -movieDirector : DocumentReference
   .
   .
   etc

Collection2 - directors
   -dirName: String
   -dirImage: String
   .
   .
   etc
```

I want to display `movieTitle` and `dirName` in a `ListTile`.

Here how I have tried to do so,

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TestPageState();
  }
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  DocumentSnapshot document;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('movies').snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> movieSnapshot) {
          if (!movieSnapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          final int messageCount = movieSnapshot.data.documents.length;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: messageCount,
            itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
              document = movieSnapshot.data.documents[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(document['movieTitle'] ?? 'title not retrieved'),
                subtitle: Text(getValue(document["movieDirector"]) ??
                    'director not retrieved'),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String getValue(DocumentReference documentReference) {
    String val;
    documentReference.get().then((onData) {
        val = onData.data["directorName"];
        print(val);
      });
    return val;
  }
}
```

Finally I couldn't be able to get the value on screen. What should I change in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about Futures and async/await so you can comfortably write such code.

The problem here is that `getValue` has to return immediately, but the `directorName` that it asks arrives sometime in the future. Therefore you simply can't get it right now.

Giving a `FutureBuilder` to the `subtitle:` is one of the options you can pursue.

Also you should consider caching the `stream` (and the future, if you implement it as per my suggestion above) so that you do not make unwanted requests. Right here I try to explain it in a presentation of mine: https://youtu.be/0gBsHLgCY6M?list=PL0bBHyAilexzBdvHookPcPZNMceciAaZf&t=1900